# DB connection as optional parameter

Tags: vb.net

VB.NET supports optional parameters as arguments to functions like such:

```
Public Function myfunction(ByVal myint As Integer, _
                Optional ByVal myoptint As Integer = 1)
```

That worked OK.
Default value for optional parameter is "MUST BE".
Regarding this I was trying to pass DB connection as optional parameter and don't know how to do it properly with "default value".

```
Public Function myfunction(ByVal myint As Integer, _
                Optional ByVal conn As ODBCConnection = WHAT??)
```

Purpose of that is that I can use external existed connection inside a function or if connection don't exist that program connects inside a function.
For example:

```
If conn Is Nothing Then ConnectToDB(dbName, dbUser, dbPass)
```

So, how to write DBconnection As optional parameter properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
Public Function myfunction(ByVal myint As Integer, _
                Optional ByVal conn As ODBCConnection = Nothing)
```

Nothing is the default value for a class in VB.Net and as ODBCConnection is a class it's default value should also be Nothing.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hm, I don't know how but that I didn't tried :) And it works, thank you!